# Search term in specific line in multiple files

Tags: windows, regex, search, grep, findstr

I would like to search a text in multiple files (within a directory) at a certain line number.

Example: I have ~100 Script Files in a directory (C:\Scripts) and I would like to scan all of these files for the term "getId()" in line number 31.

Considering I am working on Windows 10, what can I do to retreive all results (for example: file names) that include "getId()" in line number 31?

Is there maybe even any existing "GUI-based" Tool, that includes this feature out of the box?

Comment: A simple python script can do that for you, the only disadvantage being that would not have a gui

Comment: @saaranshgarg: Thanks for your comment :) It musn't have a GUI. I'm unfortunately not experienced in Python and would need more help on it. Would this approach use a line-selector / RegEx or how can I imagine it?

Comment: Wait, I'll give you the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```python
import os

lidir=os.listdir("C://Scripts") #lists all the files
for file in lidir:
    fo=open(str("C://Scripts//"+file)) #open the file
    content = fo.readlines()
    tofindin=""
    try:
        tofindin = content[30]
    except:
        continue
    x=tofindin.find("getId()") # finds
    if x != -1:
        print("Present in",file)
```

You will need to install Python to run this. Also, run this as administrator, because your scripts lie in C: directory. Save this as a '.py' file anywhere.

Comment: If you trust me, I can provide you with compiled version. Then you wouldn't need to download python

Comment: Script works fine! :) Already downloaded Python. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can try Powershell. It is already installed on Windows. Run the following:

```ps
Get-ChildItem *.ini | ForEach { $found = (Get-Content $_.name | Select -Index 30 | Select-String "getid\(\)"); if( $found.Length -gt 0){write-host $_.Name}  }
```

Replace `*.ini` with your script files' extension.